# Calculate JSP rendering time

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC with JSP and would like to calculate how long does the JSP template rendering take. 
I'm not interested in the total time from the moment the request send until the html is served, but only the template rendering time.
Is there a  way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried a profiler such as YourKit or an APM, for instance Glowroot? Hopefully they breakdown the request time detailing how much time was spent on JDBC, JSP and etc. Also remember that very likely your JSP is cached after the first use.